# How to setup web app connection so that I can run them locally in IIS express and in the Auzure cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api

**Current State:** I have created 2 Web Apps based on ASP.net 4.5.2 and WebAPI in Visual Studio 2015. One web app queries the REST API of the second web app which in turn connects to another REST API on the web.

I usually test the web apps locally on the IIS Express server. Web app one communicates with the second on via `HttpClient` using a `localhost` as host name.

**Goal:** Now I want to deploy those two web apps to Azure. There, obviously, I can't use `localhost`. I have to use the IP addresses/hostnames that are assigned by Visual Studio (not sure how to figure them out yet, but anyway). But when I change the code to use `whatever IP address` instead of `localhost` then I can't run and debug them on IIS Express locally.

**Actual Question:** How can I let web app one communicate with web app two when running in IIS Express and Azure cloud? How can I overcome the hostname issue?

Comment: You can use Config Transformations http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Applying-MSBuild-Config-Transformations-to-any-config-file-without-using-any-Visual-Studio-extensions and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx when debugging, the web.config will be overwritten. when deploying with release configuration web.config will also be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just use the web.config

In Visual Studio, for the Web project, if you click Properties > Web > Servers you can select IIS express and set a static url eg: http://localhost:51137/

I'm guessing you have done this already.

Each App then has a reference to the other, using an AppSetting, which you add to web.config

```
<add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="http://localhost:51137/" />
```

and this setting is overwritten in the Azure AppSettings configuration so it points at live.

```
<add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="https://myApp.azurewebsites.net/" />
```

Whenever webApp1 needs to call webApp2 it can construct the url from
`apiUrl + 'Foo/23'`, where `apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];`

Edit: If you log in to the 'new' Azure portal and look at the Settings for your WebApp there is an Application settings blade. The App settings section allow key/value entries which over-write the published AppSettings.

Comment: Right, the static url is set already (done by VS I guess). But I don't understand the rest of your answer. Where can I see this reference? Where can I set the azure URL? When is this overriden (during deployment)? ... (I don't have this ApiBaseUrl in my web.config)